# IO Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Refusing to marshal net.sf.json.JSONObject for security reasons

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have integrated *Deploy Hub* plugin in *Jenkins* and When i run the Jenkins job i am getting the below error, Please can anyone advise

> 12:38:03 Logged in to DeployHub as user admin
>
> 12:38:07 Deploying application Application104 to environment
>   Environment104
>
> 12:38:11 Deployment #135 started
>
> 12:38:11 IO Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Refusing to  marshal net.sf.json.JSONObject for security reasons; see
>
> https://jenkins.io/redirect/class-filter/
>
> 12:38:11 Build step 'DeployHub Interface' marked build as failure

Comment: 12:37:54 Time Elapsed 00:00:05.99
12:37:54 Archiving artifacts
12:38:03 Logged in to DeployHub as user admin
12:38:07 Deploying application Application104 to environment Environment104
12:38:11 Deployment #135 started
12:38:11 IO Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Refusing to marshal net.sf.json.JSONObject for security reasons; see https://jenkins.io/redirect/class-filter/
12:38:11 Build step 'DeployHub Interface' marked build as failure
12:38:11 Finished: FAILURE

Comment: is any body can advise here?